# How to access java web application with IP address (without doing host entry)

Tags: java, tomcat, url, web-applications

I have deployed an java web application using apache-tomcat-7.0.5 on particular server. Server ip is for example 192.168.0.145.

Below is the host entry I have done in server.xml in the tomcat's conf directory.

```
> <Host name="license.med.com" debug="0"   appBase="" unpackWARs="false"
> autoDeploy="false">
>                 <Context path="" docBase="/data/LicenseData/setup/licenseGen/WebContent/" debug="0"
> reloadable="true"  crossContext="false" />
>          </Host>
```

After starting tomcat server when I try to access web app with URL http://192.168.0.145:10880/, it shows me home page of tomcat.

After doing below host entry in hosts file :

192.168.0.145  license.med.com

when I try to access web app with URL - http://license.med.com:10880/, it shows me home page of the application.

But I would like to access the application using Ip address only. I have tried many things but not able to access the same.

If I host the same using eclipse from my local machine, I am able to access it using IP address. But same is not possible for the server where I have deployed my application.

Please help and Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure there is no sub path? have you deployed your app on the as the root app or someName.war then u need to access as http://192.168.0.145:10880/someName

Comment: Edit the index.jsp in your root tomcat folder, so it says my app <% out.print(new java.util.Date(); %> and verify you can see it? Put tomcat in your local - and deploy there manually not from eclipse. eclipse makes it easy but devs miss a few steps in real tomcat, so practice with a local tomcat too a few times a week

Comment: I have not deployed it as someName.war, but I have placed WebContent folder in the path mentioned in docbase.

Comment: Why not try in tomcat in local and access by 127.0.0.1 ? Maybe the issue is the path="" try path = "/"?

Comment: Or change the port to 10881 - maybe its pointing to some other app/ or add something unique in the index.jsp/ main servlet so your sure which deployment it is

Comment: Host name="license.med.com" you have restricted it to this domain, that's why not working from IP! tomcat looks as the IP as it would any host and does not serve it if its not in the Host deceleration or default any. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html and https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Host_Name_Aliases

Answer (score 0):

After going lots of trail and error as per the suggestions provided here and on other I finally found below solution :

I have added  tag with the I on through I want to access the Site.

Below is the tag I have added :

```
<Alias>192.168.0.145</Alias>
```

Now I can access it with below URL :

```
http://192.168.0.145:10880/
```

Thanks all for your responses!!!